# VBA to extract variable reference from string then lookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with extracting a reference from a string and performing a lookup after.

So I have a lookup table in another sheet;

Col A  |  Col B

13453 |   Place 1

13099  |  Place 2

125515 |  Place 3

12357 |  Place 4

121671 | Place 5

And I have a list of payment references that come into an import sheet like this, noting the differences in lengths;

CA13453/130

CA13099/33

CA125515/75

CA12357/1

CA121671/54

What I would like help with is VBA to find the first 5 or six numbers of the payment reference, check it against the lookup table, then paste the name of the place in the next column.  The import tab would look like this after I run the code;

Col A               | Col B on import sheet

CA13453/130 | Place 1

CA13099/33 | Place 2

CA125515/75 | Place 3

CA12357/1    | Place 4

CA121671/54 | Place 5

Let me know if you need more info and many thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to start your code, a good start would be `vlookup` based off the splitting `right(split("CA13099/33","/")(0),len(split("CA13099/33","/")(0))-2)` of the ID?

Comment: `InStr` will do if VBA. You can also just extract the payment ref number from `CA#####/##` with a combination of `MID` and `Find("/")`

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options for you. The first is a macro that will process every row in the Import sheet. The second, uses a function and you will have to put the function in every row to retrieve the location data.

First, the macro to process every row in the Import sheet. This can be invoked by pressing alt+f8, or adding a command button to your workbook that executes the macro.

```
Sub GetLocationNames()

LocationShtNm = "Locations"  ' <---- Name of the sheet that has the location data
ImportShtNm = "Import"  ' <---- Name of the sheet that has the payment data
LocationStartRow = 2 ' <----- Change to the row that has the first row of location data in the Locations sheet
ImportStartRow = 2 ' <----- Change to the row that has the first row of payment data in the Imported data sheet
LocationKeyCol = 1 ' <----- Change to column that has the location names in the locations sheet
LocationNamesCol = 2 ' <----- Change to column that has the location names in the locations sheet
ImportKeyCol = 1 ' <----- Change to the column that has the payment number in the import sheet
ImportLocCol = 2 ' <----- Change to the column that has the location in the import sheet

Set LocationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(LocationShtNm)
Set ImportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ImportShtNm)

'* Get the range for the traveller data
LocationLastRow = LocationSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ImportLastRow = ImportSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

' Loop through the import data one row at a time
For i = ImportStartRow To ImportLastRow
    LocationKey = Mid(ImportSheet.Cells(i, ImportKeyCol), 3)
    SlashLoc = InStr(LocationKey, "/")
    LocationKey = Left(LocationKey, SlashLoc - 1)

    ' Loop through the location data and find the location
    FoundLoc = False
    For j = LocationStartRow To LocationLastRow
        If Trim(LocationSheet.Cells(j, LocationKeyCol)) = LocationKey Then
            FoundLoc = True
            CurrLocation = LocationSheet.Cells(j, LocationNamesCol).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    If FoundLoc = True Then
        ImportSheet.Cells(i, ImportLocCol) = CurrLocation
    Else
        ImportSheet.Cells(i, ImportLocCol) = "Not Found"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The second is a function. You will have to put this into a cell on every row of the Import sheet, like so:

```
=GetLocationName(A2) ' Where A2 would have a payment reference number
```

Here is the macro that implements the function.

```
Function GetLocationName(CellIn)

LocationShtNm = "Locations"  ' <---- Name of the sheet that has the location data
ImportShtNm = "Import"  ' <---- Name of the sheet that has the payment data
LocationStartRow = 2 ' <----- Change to the row that has the first row of location data in the Locations sheet
ImportStartRow = 2 ' <----- Change to the row that has the first row of payment data in the Imported data sheet
LocationKeyCol = 1 ' <----- Change to column that has the location names in the locations sheet
LocationNamesCol = 2 ' <----- Change to column that has the location names in the locations sheet
ImportKeyCol = 1 ' <----- Change to the column that has the payment number in the import sheet
ImportLocCol = 2 ' <----- Change to the column that has the location in the import sheet

Set LocationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(LocationShtNm)
Set ImportSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ImportShtNm)

'* Get the range for the traveller data
LocationLastRow = LocationSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ImportLastRow = ImportSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

LocationKey = Mid(CellIn.Value, 3)
SlashLoc = InStr(LocationKey, "/")
LocationKey = Left(LocationKey, SlashLoc - 1)

' Loop through the location data and find the location
FoundLoc = False
For j = LocationStartRow To LocationLastRow
    If Trim(LocationSheet.Cells(j, LocationKeyCol)) = LocationKey Then
        FoundLoc = True
        CurrLocation = LocationSheet.Cells(j, LocationNamesCol).Value
        Exit For
    End If
Next j

If FoundLoc = True Then
    GetLocationName = CurrLocation
Else
    GetLocationName = "Not Found"
End If


End Function
```

Location Worksheet:
[image]

Import Worksheet:
[image]